# Gaussian distribution propoprties

Tags: lattice-crypto, gaussian-noise

Good day,

I've a question regarding Gaussian distribution properties over lattices :

Let $\mathcal{L}$ := $ \mathcal{L}(\,b_{1}$,..., $b_{m})$ be a lattice over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $W$ = span($b_{1}$,..,$b_{m}$)$^{\perp}$. define $\pi_{W}$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $W$.

If i sample a vector b from a Gaussian distribution of support $\mathcal{L}$, standard deviation parameter $s$ and center parameter $c \in$ span($\mathcal{L}$).

Can i pretend that $\pi_{W}(\,b)\,$ can be sampled from a Gaussian distribution of support $\pi_{W}(\,\mathcal{L})\,$, standard deviation parameter $s$ and center parameter $\pi_{W}(\,c)\,$?

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something? Surely $\pi_W(b)$ is the zero vector?

Comment: Certainly it is. but, what i was trying to say that i didn't expressed very well- and  I'm really sorry about it-; is how  the Gaussian distribution handle linear transformation such as orthogonal projections.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel's comment mentions, the answer to your question appears to be "no, for trivial reasons" (plausibly due to some typo in your question).

Still, any question of this form has a relatively straightforward answer --- namely to look into [Improved Discrete Gaussian and Subgaussian Analysis
for Lattice Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/337.pdf).
In particular, section 3 discusses how Gaussians on lattices transform under linear transformations (including projections), and seems to be what you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. I think i have an answer.)